# Unable to run Appium test with Java Client 6.1.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I have an automation project and it's working fine with java-client 5.0.4, while updating it to java-client: 6.1.0 in `pom.xml` file, then it's showing below error on IDE

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/OkHttpClient$Factory`

above error showing within a second, seems like no interaction with Appium server and as a result there is no error log on Appium server

Project: Maven

Appium server: 1.8.1

Comment: The problem is with the selenium driver. Can you mention the version of **selenium-java** that you are using or upgrade your selenium version? I am using **java-client 6.1.0** and **selenium-java 3.13.0**. Its working fine for me.

Comment: I'm using Selenium 3.13 as well, but neither 6.0.0 nor 6.1.0 works for me.  Currently I'm using Appium 1.7.2 - whenever I attempted to update to 1.8.1 everything stopped working.  I've tried all kinds of combinations, even after restoring back to 1.7.2 and am dead in the water myself.

Comment: My combination was, `java-client 6.1.0` and `selenium-java 3.14.0`, it's working fine now after changing it to `java-client 6.1.0` and `selenium-java 3.13.0`. Thanks @suban

Comment: @BillHileman I am using **java-client 6.1.0**, **selenium-java 3.13.0** and **appium server 1.8.1**, its working fine for me. I thinks you have problem with your desired capabilities initialization. You didn't mention any log or error shown in your ide or appium log.

Comment: My framework stopped working after an update, there were no code changes.  Problem is, I probably made several library updates at once and have not been able to restore it back to a stable state since.  I'm apparently not the only one reporting my current specific error, but I've not seen any offered solutions anywhere for it yet.  I keep trying, though.  I've not posted my specific problem (yet), I only dog-piled onto this particular post.  If I don't resolve my own issue in a few days, I'll likely make it a separate post with as many details as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following code with latest javaclient 6.1.0 and appium 1.8.1 desktop and it is working. Please try following code with mentioned pom.xml. It is successfully running chrome browser in emulator and test is getting passed.

```
public class AppiumClass {

    static AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;
    static DesiredCapabilities capabilities;

    @BeforeTest
    public static void start() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{


        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"),setCapsforMobileBrowser(capabilities));
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        Set<String> contextHandle = driver.getContextHandles();
        for(String str:contextHandle){
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/terms_accept")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/negative_button")).click();
        driver.context("CHROMIUM");
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");       
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("appium latest version");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//h3[@class='r'])[1]//a")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void init() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        try {
            start();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("inside catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static DesiredCapabilities setCapsforMobileBrowser(DesiredCapabilities capabilities){

        capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.8.1");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
        return capabilities;
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){

    }

}


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppiumLatest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore> false </testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need this code in git, I will add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using an older selenium version and only updating `java-client` version. Later to `java-client 6.0` you need `selenium version 3.12.0` or later. Please check and update it.

Please let us know if, even after updating it did not work